# Html + Css in one page for a toggle button without javascript

Tags: html, css

As the title said I am a newbie who's trying to merge an Html with a Css because the website I am using (getresponse) won't let me upload a different .css file.
Surely I am doing something wrong, but here is the html:

```css
#cont {
  display: none;
}

.show:focus+.hide+#cont {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#show" class="show">[Show]</a>
  <a href="#hide" class="hide"></a>
  <div id="cont">Content</div>
</div>
```

How do I do it? I tried writing the .css first but nope.

Answer (score 1):

You add CSS code in the `style` tag:

```
<style>
#cont {display: none; }
          .show:focus + .hide + #cont {display: block;}
</style>
```

Comment: It was really that easy?
Shame on me 

Thank you so much, now it works